# Why does pgadmin use the wrong port?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect to a database that runs in a docker container on a VM.

I setup the SSH tunnel and I don't get an error, so I guess that works.

But I get this error message. Which looks a bit weird, because it is about port 62917 instead port 5432.

Why is pgadmin using a seemingly random port here?

using pgadmin 4 6.8

[image]

Comment: This statement is, at least a bit, vague: "I setup the SSH tunnel and I don't get an error, so I guess that works."  What does an SSH tunnel, of which you do not share any further information, have to do with connecting to PostgreSQL ?

Comment: You can setup a connection via SSH in the SSH tunnel tab. If that does not work you get an error that tells you that the SSH connection could not be established. Since I don't get this error, I assume the SSH connection works fine.

Comment: I think it's some firewall issue, I just tried, and can connect to a PostgreSQL server on a different computer via SSH.